# Managing sessions with Angularfire, Passport and Express/Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, angularfire

I have a NodeJS/AngularJS application and I want to use `angularfire` to manage my user's login/registration at the client. E.g.

```
$firebaseAuth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(auth) {
    // communicate with backend server and redirect to secure site using auth obj
}, function(error) {});
```

After successfully logging in at the client, I want to post the `auth` object to the backend server to verify the user with Firebase. Then create a session in my NodeJS/Express application then redirect the user to a secure page. Previously I was using `passport` to create sessions from an email and password, but I don't know how to adapt `passport` to use the `auth` object retrieved by `angularfire` instead. Although there is a [passport module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-firebase-auth) for Firebase there is no working example code. Can anyone provide working code or instructions on how to verify the user with Firebase and establish a secure session in my NodeJS\Express application, preferably using passport?